# jQuery Use Data Binding

Tags: jquery, data-binding

Is something like this possible with jQuery data binding?

```
<div id="unread-messages">0</div>
```

Use jQuery data binding to assigning a var "unread-message-ids, so I can keep a list of all the IDs that make up the unread-messages count

Then bind jquery to update the count (currently 0) anytime the unread-message-ids changes (added/subtract to the list size.

Possible?